# The tag "currently-airing"

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed the [currently-airing](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/currently-airing) tag created recently. Jon Lin's proposed tag description also includes `ongoing manga series`. Should we instead name it as [ongoing](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ongoing)? "Airing" seems to apply only to anime.

There are a couple of other questions:

1. How do we handle keeping the posts updated, when a series ends? I know, this won't happen so often that we need to audit posts daily.
2. What posts should use this tags? A significant proportion of our questions (even excluding [naruto](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naruto)) are on ongoing series, so should they all use this tag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think we shouldn't have this tag at all.

When you ask a question with the [currently-airing](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/currently-airing) or even [ongoing](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ongoing) tag, what does that mean?

Are you asking about the fact that it's ongoing? Are you asking about the process of releasing ongoing series? No, you're asking about a series, which happens to be ongoing.

For instance, I ask a question regarding to how to make a table, I'll tag it [table](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/table), [construction](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/construction), but I won't tag it [hammer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hammer), just because I happen to use one.

---

In my eyes, the [ongoing](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ongoing) or [currently-airing](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/currently-airing) is a meta tag. We don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

I added the description to include manga simply because there wasn't a manga related tag, but in retrospect, I think the [currently-airing](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/currently-airing) tag should only apply to anime mainly because of how the two are produced. There's a lot of manga series, which doesn't necessarily have to follow a regular release schedule like an anime TV series does, which are ongoing. The manga medium allows the writers and publishers to produce chapters almost indefinitely, whereas a slotted TV series really doesn't have that option.

It seems that a lot of the manga related questions right now are all of series that are ongoing. However, a majority of the anime series that have questions are shows that have ended, or at the very least, has a foreseeable end to the show. Thus having the [currently-airing](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/currently-airing) tag would be more meaningful.

This does raise the question of how to deal with the tag on anime questions where the anime has ended, yet the question was asked when it was still airing.

Comment: I see, this makes sense. Thanks for clarifying. Didn't mean to pick on your description. :)